# Add struct in Visual Studio [Visualizer]?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to add a section for QHostAddress in the [Visualizer] section of autoexp.dat, but the data in QHostAddress is actually held in QHostAddressPrivate which isn't known to Visual Studio (because it's private to Qt). Is there any way of defining a struct in autoexp.dat, casting an unknown pointer or something similar so I can show the IP address held within?

Update:

I played around with this and managed to get the code below to work. However, it's a bit clunky for several reasons:

1. It's using a lot of casting. It would be much neater to declare a struct and use this.
2. I can only show the IPv6 groups as hex with the '0x' header which makes the address a bit messy.
3. I'd like to be able to show both the IPv4 and IPv6 data as children but I can't figure out how to create strings with multiple parts in the "children" section.
4. Visual Studio won't accept colons in the IPv6 address, even when declared in a string. If I do this I get the error:

> ERROR! Autoexp.dat:line(1687) for 'QHostAddress|*::QHostAddress':
>   Expected ')' for end of #else
>   ERROR! Autoexp.dat:line(1687) for 'QHostAddress|*::QHostAddress':
>   Preview rule failed to parse
>   ERROR! Autoexp.dat:line(1687) for 'QHostAddress|*::QHostAddress':
>   Failed to match ')' for preview/children rule

```
[Visualizer]
;QT_DEBUG_START
QHostAddress|*::QHostAddress{
    preview
    (
        #(
            #if (*((quint32 *)$c.d.d) != 0) (
                #("IPv4=", [*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 3), u],
                ".", [*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 2), u],
                ".", [*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 1), u],
                ".", [*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0), u])
            ) #elif ((*(((quint32 *)$e.d.d) + 1)) + (*(((quint32 *)$e.d.d) + 2)) + (*(((quint32 *)$e.d.d) + 3)) + (*(((quint32 *)$e.d.d) + 4)) != 0) (
                #("IPv6=",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x04) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x05))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x06) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x07))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x08) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x09))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x0A) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x0B))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x0C) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x0D))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x0E) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x0F))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x10) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x11))), x],
                ".",
                [(quint16)((*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x12) << 0x8) | (*(((quint8 *)$e.d.d) + 0x13))), x])
            )
        )
    )
    children
    (
        #(
            [d]: [$c.d.d, x]
        )
    )
}
;QT_DEBUG_END
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to create this in StackOverflow but I didn't notice I'd switched websites.